# Styled-component stopped working on one page. React

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm using styled-components on my app. Styling works on home page, and all other pages except one List page. When I open this page all components (a mean tags which i created by styled-components) rendering on page, but styling not working. After I open this page, when i go to another pages which worked correctly before, styles on this pages stop working also. It's come back after page reload, but stop working again after opening List page.

here is List page code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import {
    Footer,
    ListFilters,
    ListProduct,
    Navbar,
    SearchFilterItem,
} from '../components'

const ListContainer = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
`
const ListWrapper = styled.div`
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 93vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px 0px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: ${(props) => props.o};
`
const ProductsContainer = styled.div`
    flex: 5;
    align-self: flex-start;
`
const ListHeader = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0px 0px 15px 20px;
`
const ListHeaderTop = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
`
const ListHeaderBottom = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
`
const ListHeadeTitle = styled.h1`
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 500;
`
const FilterBy = styled.select`
    padding: 2px 5px;
    width: 180px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #666;
    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
`
const FilterByOption = styled.option``
const Products = styled.div`
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    gap: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
`

const List = () => {
    const location = useLocation()
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [error, setError] = useState(false)
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

    const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
        categoryFilter: [],
        brandFilter: [],
        sizeFilter: [],
        genderFilter: [],
    })

    const [cat, setCat] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (location?.state?.item) {
            setCat({ ...cat, category: location?.state?.item })
        } else if (location?.state?.brand) {
            setCat({ ...cat, brand: location?.state?.brand })
        } else {
            setCat(null)
        }
    }, [])

    // console.log(location.state)

    const qs =
        cat &&
        Object.keys(cat)
            .map(
                (key) =>
                    `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(cat[key])}`
            )
            .join('&')

    useEffect(() => {
        let isMounted = true
        const source = axios.CancelToken.source()
        const getProducts = async () => {
            setLoading(true)
            try {
                const res = await axios.get(
                    cat
                        ? `http://localhost:5000/api/products?${qs}`
                        : `http://localhost:5000/api/products`,

                    {
                        cancelToken: source.token,
                    }
                )
                if (isMounted) {
                    setProducts(res.data)
                    setError(null)
                    const allCats = [
                        ...new Set(
                            res.data.map((item) => item.category).flat()
                        ),
                    ]
                    const allBrands = [
                        ...new Set(res.data.map((item) => item.brand)),
                    ]
                    const allGenders = [
                        ...new Set(res.data.map((item) => item.gender)),
                    ]
                    const allSizes = [
                        ...new Set(res.data.map((item) => item.size).flat()),
                    ]
                    setFilters({
                        categoryFilter: allCats,
                        brandFilter: allBrands,
                        sizeFilter: allSizes,
                        genderFilter: allGenders,
                    })
                }
            } catch (error) {
                if (isMounted) {
                    setError(error.message)
                    setProducts(null)
                }
            } finally {
                isMounted && setLoading(false)
            }
        }
        getProducts()

        const cleanUp = () => {
            isMounted = false
            source.cancel()
        }

        return cleanUp
    }, [cat, qs])

    const onToggleFilter = (categ, id) => {
        if (cat && Object.entries(cat).flat().includes(id)) {
            setCat(
                Object.fromEntries(
                    Object.entries(cat).filter(([key, value]) => value !== id)
                )
            )
        } else {
            if (categ === 'gender') {
                setCat({ ...cat, gender: id })
            } else if (categ === 'size') {
                setCat({ ...cat, size: id })
            } else if (categ === 'brand') {
                setCat({ ...cat, brand: id })
            } else {
                setCat({ ...cat, category: id })
            }
        }
    }

    const onDeleteFilter = (id) => {
        // console.log(id)
        setCat(
            Object.fromEntries(
                Object.entries(cat).filter(([key, value]) => value !== id)
            )
        )
    }

    console.log(cat)

    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            <ListContainer>
                <ListWrapper o={loading ? 0.35 : 1}>
                    {/* {loading ? (
                        <Spinner />
                    ) : (
                        <> */}
                    <ListFilters
                        cat={cat}
                        setCat={setCat}
                        filters={filters}
                        onToggleFilter={onToggleFilter}
                    />

                    <ProductsContainer>
                        <ListHeader>
                            <ListHeaderTop>
                                <ListHeadeTitle>
                                    {products.length} result
                                    {products.length > 1 ? 's' : null}
                                    {' are listed for your search'}
                                </ListHeadeTitle>
                                <FilterBy>
                                    <FilterByOption>Sort By:</FilterByOption>
                                    <FilterByOption value="new">
                                        Newest Arrivals
                                    </FilterByOption>
                                    <FilterByOption value="low">
                                        Price: Low
                                    </FilterByOption>
                                    <FilterByOption value="high">
                                        Price: High
                                    </FilterByOption>
                                </FilterBy>
                            </ListHeaderTop>
                            <ListHeaderBottom>
                                {cat &&
                                    Object.keys(cat).map((key) => (
                                        <SearchFilterItem
                                            onDeleteFilter={onDeleteFilter}
                                            key={key}
                                            info={cat[key]}
                                        />
                                    ))}
                            </ListHeaderBottom>
                        </ListHeader>

                        <Products>
                            {products.map((item) => (
                                <ListProduct key={item._id} {...item} />
                            ))}
                        </Products>
                    </ProductsContainer>
                    {/* </>
                    )} */}
                </ListWrapper>
            </ListContainer>
            <Footer />
        </>
    )
}

export default List
```

Comment: Here is what you can do: throw out some parts of the page and see if the problem is still present. rinse and repeat. until you find that after you removed a portion of the coe the problem is gone. then revert the change and look closely in that section.

Comment: @Martin Thank you for your reply, I did exactly as yo wrote, and solve the problem. The problem was in image component, it was connected to the image url which component fetch from backend. Styles come back when i deleted product with this image url from backend. Thank you!